# PowerShell not excluding folder

Tags: powershell

I have a very simple script(or I thought) where I'm trying to use recurse to go through each folder and subfolder and check if that folder has "backup.log" in it, while excluding the OneDrive folder. I tried everything I can think of, searched online and tried the solutions provided but PowerShell just keeps going in to the OneDrive folder. Some of the common scripts I tried are below. Any help is much appreciated.

```
$exclude = @("$env:OneDrive")
get-childitem -Path $env:USERPROFILE -Filter 'backup.log' -Recurse  -Exclude $exclude

get-childitem -Path $env:USERPROFILE -Filter 'backup.log' -Recurse  | Where {$_.FullName -notmatch "$env:onedrive"}

get-childitem -Path $env:USERPROFILE -Filter 'backup.log' -Recurse  | Where-Object { !($_.FullName).StartsWith($env:OneDrive) }

get-childitem -Path $env:USERPROFILE -Filter 'backup.log' -Recurse  | Where {$_.FullName -notmatch "$env:onedrive\*"}
```

I tried some more things but it's pretty much along the same logic. I also tried changing the environmental variable with writing the path manually but had the same result. Also tried the DirectoryName instead of FullName.

Edit:
Here is the error I'm getting:

> **Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\username\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\master\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard1.1'. At line:1 char:1 + get-childitem -Path $env:USERPROFILE -Filter 'backup.log' -Recurse | + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ReadError: (C:\Users\username\netstandard1.1:String) [Get-ChildItem], DirectoryNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand –**

Comment: Your examples look fine, at least the `StartsWith` one, what is `$env:OneDrive` ?

Comment: Doesn't work tho and it is driving me crazy. The $env:OneDrive is basically C:\users\username\OneDrive - MyCompany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-exclude doesn't work with -recurse or -filter; excluding the full path doesn't work:

```
get-childitem -Path $env:USERPROFILE -Exclude 'OneDrive - Company' | 
  get-childitem -Filter backup.log -Recurse
```

In regex, backslashes in paths need to be escaped \\:

```
get-childitem -Path $env:USERPROFILE -Filter 'backup.log' -Recurse  | 
  Where {$_.FullName -notmatch [regex]::escape("$env:onedrive")}
```

.StartsWith() is case sensitive:

```
get-childitem -Path $env:USERPROFILE -Filter 'backup.log' -Recurse  | 
  Where-Object { !($_.FullName.tolower()).StartsWith($env:OneDrive.tolower()) }
```

Or -notlike:

```
dir -r ~ backup.log | ? fullname -notlike $env:onedrive*
```

Enable long paths?

```
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled 1 -type dword

# or
get-childitem -LiteralPath "\\?\$env:userprofile" -Recurse -filter backup.log
```

Comment: Thanks @js2010 unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

get-childitem : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\username\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\master\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard1.1'.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-childitem -Path $env:USERPROFILE -Filter 'backup.log' -Recurse  |
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Users\username\netstandard1.1:String) [Get-ChildItem], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: @Besiktas Please add the error message to the question.

Comment: There's always -erroraction silentlycontinue.  I wonder if it's a long path problem.

Comment: I have a feeling that the error is related to a long path problem. But the code should skip that part of the folder. For testing purposes I added a "backup.log" to a folder inside the OneDrive and it found it. Which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: ErrorAction wouldn't work in my case because it finds folders inside the OneDrive folder.

Comment: Shouldn't that first thing work?  Or one of the ways to enable long paths.

Comment: get-childitem -Path $env:USERPROFILE -Exclude 'OneDrive - Company' | 
  get-childitem -Filter backup.log -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Directory -notlike $env:USERPROFILE 

I added the where-object at the end, and it worked on you first example. I will mark your answer as correct. Please feel free to add the last part.

Comment: Why did you need the last part?  Without a wildcard, it might as well be -ne

Comment: I guess you're hiding the files in the main directory?

Comment: I tried it without that part but it didn't work. It was going back and finding random files within the users profile. Why? I really don't know. I spent so much time on this that I'm OK as long as it works. lol